# Minimal distance between the origin and intersection of $x^2 = 2yz$ and $x^2+3y^2+2z^2 = 30$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the minimal distance between the origin and intersection of $x^2 = 2yz$ and $x^2+3y^2+2z^2 = 30$

Attempt:
$2yz+3y^2+2z^2 = 30$

I called $f(y,z) = 2yz+3y^2+2z^2$

Then, $\nabla f(y,z) = (2z+6y,2y+4z) = 0 \Rightarrow y=z=0$

So the critical point is $(0,0,0)$, which is clearly a minimum. But, I think this is wrong, because the minimum point is not necessarily the minimal distance to the origin. How do I get the closest point to the origin?

Comment: The distance from the origin depends on the value of $x$, too.

Comment: I used $x^2 =2yz$ on the second surface, to get the intersection of both. Isn't it right?

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Of course, but then you cannot forget about $x$ in computing the distance from the origin. You have to find the minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ under **two** constraints, $x^2=2yz$ and $x^2+3y^2+2z^2=30$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown the idea indeed is to use lagrange multiplier. But I didn't manage to get the distance to the origin in the system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer my own question based on the hints.

Define $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, $\varphi_1(x,y,z)=x^2-2yz$ and $\varphi_2(x,y,z)=x^2+3y^2+2z^2$

By doing $\nabla f = \lambda_1\varphi_1+\lambda_2\varphi_2$, we have

$(2x,2y,2z)=\lambda_1(2x,-2z,-2y)+\lambda_2(2x,6y,4z)$

$2x = \lambda_12x+\lambda_22x$

$2y =-\lambda_12z+\lambda_26y$

$2z=-\lambda_12y+\lambda_24z$

Together with $\varphi_1 = 0$ and $\varphi_2=30$, calculating this system of equation, we have:

$y=(3/2)z$ and $x =\pm\sqrt3z$, so $z=\pm\sqrt{60/19}$

And the points are $(\pm\sqrt3\sqrt{60/19},(3/2)\sqrt{60/19},\sqrt{60/19})$ and $(\pm\sqrt3\sqrt{60/19},-(3/2)\sqrt{60/19},-\sqrt{60/19})$

which are all minimum points as $\det Hf(x,y,z) = 8>0$, as

$Hf(x,y,z)=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

The minimum distance to the origin is given by the Euclidean norm. To make the problem less complex, we can solve the equivalent problem, minimizing the **square** of the Euclidean distance $D(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ subject to both of your equality constraints, $x^2 = 2yz$ and $x^2+3y^2+ 2z^2 = 30$.

You don't have to solve it using Lagrange multipliers necessarily, but that indeed would be a very elegant way of doing so.

Comment: We still have to be careful in applying the Lagrange multipliers method since $x^2=2yz$ does not give a smooth compact constraint alone and the given intersection has two connected components.

Answer (score 2):

i have $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=f(x,y,z)$$ for $$x^2$$ we have $$x^2=2yz$$ and further
$$2z^2=30-x^2-3y^2=2yz-3/2y^2$$ we get
$$z^2=15-yz-\frac{3}{2}y^2$$ and we have to optimize
$$\sqrt{yz-\frac{1}{2}y^2+15}$$
you can consider the function $$h(y,z)=yz+15-\frac{1}{2}y^2$$ and compute the partial derivatives with respect to $$y,z$$

Comment: I would optimize the square of that...

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP knows what he/she has to optimize, the point is **how** to do that.

Comment: For the OP: can you explain how this "answer" actually helped you?

Comment: oh man, we have reduced the number of variables to two and we don't Need Lagrange Multiplier method

Comment: In order that $x^2=2yz$, $y$ and $z$ have to be the same sign, and your $h(y,z)$ does not account for that. So yes, the problem has less variables, but you still have to get rid of a constraint.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I'm learning the Lagrange Multipliers in a real analysis course. But during the course we almost don't have examples, so I find it difficult to manage the theorems in the real cases. This answer helped me to get it less abstract.

Comment: @BrunoMazeto: this answer does not really solve your problem (by the addressed issues) but if you are fine with that, I am fine too. I just wonder how many points this "solution" would get on a actual exam: few, I guess, since it is just a bunch of algebraic manipulations, not really capturing the geometry or the subtleties of the given configuration. Anyway, anyone is allowed to take the *less abstract, and wrong* path.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I see your point, and took a better look on the answers and I tried to do it myself. I think I got it.